# I'm having problems with scipy.optimize.curve_fit and getting RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit to fit a curve to an array.
This is my code:

```
def foubert(t,K,n):
    return (1+((1-0.0620281576)**(1-n)-1)*np.exp(-(1-n)*K*(t-3)))**(1/(1-n))

foub_params, _ = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(foubert,phi[:,0],phi[:,1])
K_f,n_f = foub_params
```

The closest I have got it to my curve by playing with parameters is around K = 0.06 and n = 2.5, however my code keeps returning n as ~1 and giving me a Runtime Warning as there is a 1/(1-n) term in the equation. Since n is demonstrably not 1, how do I fix this?

This is the error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return (1+((1-0.0620281576)**(1-n)-1)*np.exp(-(1-n)*K*(t-3)))**(1/(1-n))
```

Comment: Since n is 1 or very close to it, you are getting 0 in denominator, hence the error. I am not sure why you think n is not 1. Print n to see. Also, you might want to break apart the equation into pieces for debugging. It is much cleaner and easier to see where issues are. The final version can be like this once no issues anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

When using `curve_fit` if you don't provide an initial starting point (`p0`) then it uses `[1, 1]`. As you have divide by zero at `n=1` in your case you **must** provide an initial estimate.

If you know that `n > 1` (I suspect it might from the form of the equation) then you could also define `bounds`.

For example, using `K=1, n=2` as the starting point and requiring that `n>1`:

```py
foub_params, _ = curve_fit(foubert, phi[:,0],phi[:,1], p0=[1, 2], bounds=[(-np.inf, 1.0), (np.inf, np.inf)])
```

More details can be found at the documentation for [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit)